# Why is primary key a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a CRUD app in PHP & MySql. It uses two tables, called *users* and *medical_records*:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`validation_code` text NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`telefon` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`oras` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`adresa` text,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE medical_records (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fo` VARCHAR(255),
  `condition` VARCHAR(255),
  `transfer` VARCHAR(255),
  `memo` text(1024),
  `body_temperature` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FK_medical_records_1
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The "business logic" of these tables is: every user has one (*only* one) medical record.

I used and tested the application when it only had the *users* table. Register and login *worked fine*, so I conclude that the *problem's source can't be the application's (PHP) code*.

I later doped the *users* table and added the 2 fresh tables the application now uses (*users* and *medical_records*).

At this moment whenever I try to register a second user, I get the error:

```
QUERY FAILED: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This happens despite the fact that both tables have *auto incremented primary keys*. What could be the explanation of that?

Comment: You say that both tables have auto-incremented primary keys, but I don't see any auto-increment in your `users` table.

Comment: If this problem persists after you fix the auto increment problem in your first table, please [edit] your question to show the sequence of queries used to register new users.

Comment: Tagged with `jQuery`, huh?

Comment: Truncate with the table and try again. 

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUCATE `users`;
TRUCATE `medical_records`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `id` in the `users` table is not set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. that's why this happens.

Comment: Silly me! Thank you! :)